# Connecting BigQuery to Python in a SQL Server Job

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I want to create a job on SQL Server to run systematically with a Python script.

This Python script is different because its connected to BigQuery and the authentication is manual: I have to open a link in my Google Account, get a code and then paste the code on Python to get authenticated.

I have already authenticated in a Jupyter Notebook, but when running the job it always returns an error.

Does anyone of you know how to solve this? Can I authenticate using credentials, like when connecting Python to SQL?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why not use SQL Server Agent? It's whole role is for scheduled tasks.

Comment: @Larnu I am using SQL Server Agent. The problem is that when the script runs the cell that reads the table from BigQuery it gets an error because of the method of authentication that's needed. You have to manually insert the password

Comment: So you're using SQL Server, to run a Python Script, that then connects to a Google Big Query instance? Sounds like, instead, you should be using some kind of middleware then, and not SQL Server Agent. Especially if you're not actually doing anything with SQL Server other than to automate the task.